# How to list all prepared statements for all active sessions?

Tags: postgresql, prepared-statement, postgresql-9.1, database-administration

I know that there is a way to list all prepared statements for the current session by selecting all rows from the `pg_prepared_statements` table, but is there a way to see all prepared statements for **all active sessions**? I think I'm looking for something like an administrator function, but I can't find anything like it in the docs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nope. AFAIK prepared statements are local to a backend; other backends just don't know they exist. You'd need to modify the server to add additional inter-process communication to allow one backend to ask the others about prepared statements.

The backends initally appeared to share the same `pg_prepared_statements` table storage, as:

```
SELECT relfilenode FROM pg_class WHERE  relname = 'pg_prepared_statements';
```

returns the same relfilenode from different backends. I was surprised, as I thought prepared statements had no on-disk presence. If they were on disk I guess you could use the functions from the [pageinspect contrib module](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pageinspect.html) to read the raw tuples or table pages. Visibility would be a problem; how would you know what was related to a dead/terminated backend, and what was valid?

I tried that, and found that `pg_prepared_statements` is actually a view:

```
regress=# SELECT * FROM heap_page_items(get_raw_page('pg_prepared_statements', 1));
ERROR:  cannot get raw page from view "pg_prepared_statements"
```

specifically a view over the `pg_prepared_statement()` function. So there's nothing to inspect. It's backend internal.

This seems like one of those "... but why would you do that?" questions, which is often a sign that someone is asking about a *solution* they've envisioned to their real problem, rather than asking about their real problem.

So: Why do you want that? What's the real problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Yeah, you're right, I'm trying to narrow down a problem that I am too uncertain about to summarize in a form of a question. I think it may have something to do with cached prepared statements returning rows with values that have been there before the last `UPDATE`.

Comment: @IgorZinov'yev It's exceedingly unlikely that prepared statements would be related to your queries seeing old data. Prepared statements have no result-cache or data cache, only a plan cache. The only way I could possibly imagine that happening would be if you `DROP`ped a partition in a table inheritance structure and the prepared statements' plans weren't flushed, but Pg is very careful with dependency tracking for prepared statements to prevent that sort of thing.

Comment: @IgorZinov'yev You probably need to look into transaction isolation (are you in `READ COMMITED` or `SERIALIZABLE` isolation?), transaction demarcation (do your tx's start and end where you think they do), etc.

Comment: You are right, it wasn't related to prepared statements in any way. It was related to improper meta tag placement, which caused browser page reloading, which caused invalid cached data being used on the page. I stumbled on the problem by accident and to say that I'm surprised is to say nothing :)

Answer (score 0):

.

**What's the real problem you're trying to solve?**

I have a partitioned table xxx.yyy

The problem is that when I try:

`VACUUM FULL VERBOSE xxx.yyy_69;`

I see:

```
INFO:  "yyy_69": found 0 removable, 3648431 nonremovable row versions in 72968 pages
DETAIL:  0 dead row versions cannot be removed yet.
```

As I know there can by 3 causes:

1. Long-running transactions (*but I made : ALTER all_application_users with nologin; SELECT pg_terminate_backend(all_pids)* )
2. Abandoned replication slots (*I don`t use replication slots*)
3. Orphaned prepared transactions

(**And I think that's the point**)

The problem solved only after

**pg_ctl restart**
VACUUM FULL VERBOSE xxx.yyy_69;
ALTER all_application_users with login;