# Count of all prepared statements (all connections) in mysql

Tags: mysql, prepared-statement, admin

My question is similar to [How to list all prepared statements for all active sessions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12159422/how-to-list-all-prepared-statements-for-all-active-sessions), but for MySQL.

I have a program (prosody XMPP server) that seems to be leaking prepared statements. To diagnose the problem, I want a list of all "open" prepared statements. (even prepared statements by 'dead' connections, if such exist)

The statements in question are, as far as I can tell, all created by the MySQL user 'prosody', so I'd like to list all statements created by this user. However, it'd be also nice to have a list of all statements for all users.

I am not fully aware of the prepared statement's lifecycle/possible states, so details in that regard are very welcome.

Answer (score 14):

It turned out to be very simple:

```
SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE '%prepared_stmt_count%';
```